# Get both the key and the index using Jade iteration

Tags: html, templates, loops, iteration, pug

As described here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/, it is easy enough to either get the index or the key. But is there a way to get both?
This:

```
ul
  each val, index in {"day": "Wed", "link": "url", "message": "three"}
    li#item-= index + ': ' + val
```

Outputs this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-">day: Wed</li>
  <li id="item-">link: url</li>
  <li id="item-">message: three</li>
</ul>
```

But I want this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-0">day: Wed</li>
  <li id="item-1">link: url</li>
  <li id="item-2">message: three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that JavaScript does not guarantee the order of keys in an object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you only get an index if you are iterating over an array, so the jade documentation is a little confusing with its example. I'll give you three options for how to accomplish this. Choose your own adventure!

#### option 1: Keep your original input and build your own index

```
ul
  -var index = 0
  each val, key in {day: "Wed", link: "url", message: "three"}
    li(id="item-#{index++}") #{key}: #{val}
```

#### option 2: Change your input to an array of arrays

```
ul
  each val, index in [["day", "Wed"], ["link", "url"], ["message", "three"]]
    li(id="item-#{index}") #{val[0]}: #{val[1]}
```

#### option 3: Change your input to an array of objects

```
ul
  each val, index in [{day: "Wed"}, {link: "url"}, {message: "three"}]
    li(id="item-#{index}") #{Object.keys(val)[0]}: #{val[Object.keys(val)[0]]}
```

The first option is probably what you want, but the others may be interesting to read.

Comment: Thanks for this. It set me on the path but assigning the attribute didn't work with the `(id="item-#{index}")` syntax. This more Javascripty syntax worked for me: `(id="item-"+index)`. Perhaps a change in Jade versions/syntax since the original post? [codepen example with each example above|http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBavMG]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this already answered question, I wasn't able to get any of these to work reliably with PyJade. I can't find the page that referred me to this tip, but it's worked perfectly for me.

Add this to your `__init__.py` file to added the `enumerate` function to your pyjade environment.

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(enumerate=enumerate)
```

Then, you can use it in your templates like any other pythonic enumeration loop:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(list_of_whatevs)
    {{ idx }}, {{ val }}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One more option using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (and Pug 2.0.4):

```
ul
  each entry, index in Object.entries({day: 'Wed', link: 'url', message: 'three'})
    - const [key, val] = entry
    li(id=`item-${index}`) #{key}: #{val}
```